# Making 2 forms under the same TaskBar Application

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get 2 forms to be under the same task bar application. It causes duplication like this here:[image: Image1]

I have the form follow the main form but I do not know how to make both forms under the same Task Bar application(If that makes any since). For the second form, I have chose False for ShowToTaskBar option in VS. I am using VB.Net As well. Thanks!

Comment: you could try: put all on one form, or use an MDI interface with a static section for global information and show your main form in the middle.

Comment: I have already looked at MDI but it does not suit what I want to do. I am happy with using 2 forms since I have the code set up to it but how would I just make it all go under one application process so to say? Is there a way? I can't find any sources that say how.

Comment: I am guessing that is a no @Jeremy